# Angular child routes without nested urls

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Let our example model have `Users`, which can belong to `Groups` as m2m via `UserGroups`, and be friends with other `Users` as m2m via `UserFriends`.

And the supposed ux can go as: select group -> select user -> select friend; or just search a user by name.

The "default" child route urls look like this:

```
/groups/
/groups/:group_id/
/groups/:group_id/:user_id/
/groups/:group_id/:user_id/:user_id(friend)/;

/user_search/
/user_search/:search_string/
/user_search/:search_string/:user_id/
```

However those are not premalinks: users can change groups, friends and even names over time. I can change it to middle entities with softdelete and cache searches on server:

```
/groups/
/groups/:group_id/
/groups/:group_id/:user_group_id/
/groups/:group_id/:user_group_id/:user_friend_id/;

/user_search/
/user_search/:search_hash/
/user_search/:search_hash/:user_id/
```

However those are not semantic. What I want here is:

```
/groups/
/group/:group_id/
/user/:user_id/?group=:groupId
/user/:user_id(friend)/?friendTo=:userId &friendGroup=:groupId;

/user_search/
/user_search/:search_string/
/user/:user_id/?search=:search_string
```

I know I can just set absolute urls for componentless routes with child routes rendered to separate outlets. However this way the topmost component has to know about all possible descendants (to prepare outlets), and components get reinitialized each time, instead of keeping their state like with normal child routing.

So is it possible to get route structure I want without component reinitialization?

Comment: Why is component re-initialization a problem here? If the user changes route from _/groups/.._ to _/user/..,_ you want to show a different component anyway, right?

Comment: @WoutervanKoppen Because I want to keep already used selectors on the screen rather than make user click "back" several times. With the default url `/groups/:group_id/:user_id/:user_id(friend)/` dom structure would be `appOutlet > groupSelector > groupOutlet > userSelector > userOutlet > userDetails > friendOutlet > userDetails` and I want to keep this structure just with different urls.

Comment: I think technically it is possible do have completely different routes pointing to the same component without component reinitialization. But then you need to use wildcards in all route definitions, such that always the same route is matched, resulting only in different wildcard values. Note that 2 different routes to the same component already force the component to reininitialize. I would not bother about that too much, actually.

Comment: Well, for now I just created a custom matcher, which uses 'data.path' instead of 'path', and it works, but it feels wrong that such a minor alteration breaks compatibility with regular routes, instead of hooking in somehow.